Caught segfault error while installing R package "sf" in Ubuntu
I am using R (version 4.4.0) with RStudio (2024.04.0 Build 735) in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. I tried to install the sf-package. However, when it tests whether the installed package can be loaded from temporary location, I get the following error message (snippet):
[...]
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
*** caught segfault ***
address 0x62ed546a6dde, cause 'memory not mapped'
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ERROR: loading failed
[...]
My IT skills are mediocre, so I do not have a clue, what is happening there. I just know that segmentation-faults are no good. Can anyone please help?

I assume you are trying to install the sf version from CRAN? Are the System Requirements installed? Which versions? Maybe try updating those?

(I have installed sf recently on a Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS system without any issues.)

@Roland Thanks for your quick reply. I double checked the sys requirements for sf. I have GDAL 3.6.4, GEOS 3.11.1, PROJ 9.1.1 and sqlite3. So this does not seem to be the problem.

This may be one of those rare cases where "try rebooting" might work.  It's possible some other system update is incomplete, leading to internal mapping errors of some sort.

The error message resolved at some point, even if I did not change anything.
